# Assembly db takes up one byte, but on my machine it takes up 4?

Tags: assembly

I was following a tutorial online where a guy was using assembly with a flat assembler to create an OS from scratch. He shows how it's done and as i followed him i realized that when he checked his assembly with his hex editor, it shows that his assembly "db 1" looks like "01" in his hex editor, it only takes up one byte; but when i try that i get "64 62 20 31" where 64 = "d", 62 = "b", 20 = empty space, and 31 = the one.

I'm running on windows vista and he looks to be running on Linux but never says, so i'm wondering if this has something to do with it, is it possible for me to create one byte on my machine through assembly the same way he does? Having the extra bytes seems very wasteful to me if there's a different way to do it.

Comment: I suppose he actually run assembler on this file and opened result in hex editor, while you opened assembler file in hex editor.

Comment: If it's not too time consuming here's the link to the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWGDG7ReLSg right at 14.33 is where he shows his work.

Comment: Hey "zch" how do you open the result of an assembly in a hex editor, i thought you had to save it as .asm and then view that file in a hex editor.

Comment: zch is right. When you open your file with an hex editor, you see the content of your file in binary (but shown in hex-format, because it is a hex editor). The file name ending, does not matter. You can change it to .jpg or .asm or .txt. The result will be the same. What you really need to do, is getting an assembler and use the assembler on your source-code file (.asm or whatever). This will produce another file (your program).

Comment: Thanks "Blechdose" i'm looking into it now.

Comment: And yes, he is using linux. Probably xubuntu or sth like that. You already mentioned the assembler you need to follow his videos: "flat assembler" which is also know as "FASM". Probably it is easier for you to set up a linux system or a virtual machine with linux inside, to be able to use the same shell codes to assemble your code as he is doing it. Because there is probably a difference in using FASM in linux and windows.

Comment: I took my .asm file and opened it in fasm and then compiled it creating a .bin file, i then opened that in my hex editor and it shows exactly what his shows. So i'm guess i was looking at the .asm file when he was looking at the .bin file and i got confused.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, i'm new to assembly and got caught up with this dumb mistake, but is easy to do when your trying to wrap your head around so many new things at once. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `.asm` file is a text source file that is used as an input to a program called an [assembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language#Assembler). Examples of assemblers include `gas`, and `nasm`.

The assembler generates an output file containing all of the machine code bytes corresponding to the program and data specified in the `.asm` file. The processor can execute the code in this file directly, when it is loaded into the correct place in memory.

You were looking at the source code for the program and not the generated output file.

Answer (score 0):

What you might be referring to is the assembly, in which case the instruction *is* `db 1`.

However, the actual assemblage of that instruction may produce simply `01`.